# SOLID DDD ORM request (to use clean entities and repositories) for .NET

Tags: .net, orm, domain-driven-design, solid-principles

Is there a ORM that would

- leave my entities classes clean, withouth any attributes for properties and classes
- would not be ActiveRecord pattern so it should not have entity.Save/Delete etc.

optional: able to execute stored procedures and parse the result into entityies

Comment: Are you targeting any specific platform/language/framework? E.g. .NET, Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like NHibernate is what you need. This uses a mapping file (in XML) to map the properties of classes to the database. Entities are managed through a SessionManager interface.

Documentation is [here](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html).

A mapping file can also map from a stored procedure to your persistent objects. Details [here](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query).

Comment: Those links are to an older (1.2) version of NHibernate.  More recent documentation is here: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html

Comment: Mark - I agree about "wait and see" regarding the Entity Framework.

Comment: Agree. Mapping can however also be done with attributes (which isn't POCO and not what the asker wanted), and with C# (http://fluentnhibernate.org/).

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is commonly referred to as **Persistence Ignorance**. It seems that the preferred framework for that is NHibernate, so I second Jeremy McGee's answer.

For completeness' sake I'd like to point out Microsoft's Entity Framework will get Persistence Ignorance in the next version (.NET 4) - they call it *POCO support*. Whether it will actually turn out to be any good remains to be seen...